# number_in_month exercise (SML list iteration)

Tags: list, date, iteration, sml

I need to take a list of dates and a list of months and get a total count of the amount of dates that are in any of the months listed. Thus returning a single integer

I had a previously defined `number_in_month` function which takes in a list of
dates and a single month and returns the amount of dates that fall in that
month. It has been tested and works correctly. I use this as the foundation for
the latter function. I've traced through the `number_in_months` function many
times and I can't seem to find out whats wrong but it is simply not yielding the right answer

```
fun number_in_month (datelist : (int*int*int)list, month : int)  = 

let
fun count(x : int , datelist : (int*int*int)list)=
if null (tl datelist)
then x
else if #2(hd datelist) = month
then count(x+1, tl datelist)
else count(x, tl datelist)

in

if #2(hd datelist) = month
then count(1, datelist)
else count(0, datelist)

end
```

```
fun number_in_months (datelist : (int*int*int)list, monthlist : (int)list)=
let 
fun count(x : int, monthlist : (int)list)=
if null (tl monthlist)
then x
else count((x + number_in_month(datelist, hd monthlist)), tl monthlist) 

in
count (( number_in_month(datelist, hd monthlist), tl monthlist))
end
```

Answer (score 7):

As you have stated, you just have to use the previous function `number_in_month`. Remembering that `number_in_month` takes a list of dates and a single month, and returns the number of matching months in the list of dates. Thus All there is needed to create `number_in_months`, is to call `number_in_month` for each element in the new list of months, with the original list of dates to be checked.

Such a solution could look like

```
fun number_in_months (dates, months) =
    if null months then
      0
    else
      number_in_month(dates, hd months) + number_in_months(dates, tl months)
```

However when you use pattern matching, you can shorten it down and make it even more readable

```
fun number_in_months (dates, []) = 0
  | number_in_months (dates, d::ds) =
      number_in_month(dates, d) + number_in_months(dates, ds)
```

There is absolutely no reason for creating a `count` function, carrying around a "state". This seems to be your imperative mind, at play :) 
Take for example this simple function which will sum all element of a list

```
fun sum [] = 0
  | sum (x::xs) = x + sum xs
```

or even creating a length function (which is actually similar to your count function)

```
fun length [] = 0
  | length (x::xs) = 1 + length xs
```

Instead of repeating a lot of good stuff already mentioned so many times, I encouraging you to go read these [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsml%5D%20number_in_month%20is:question) and their answers.

**Update**

I  also wanted to show you how to format you code in a better way

```
fun number_in_month (datelist : (int*int*int) list, month : int)  =
    let
      fun count (x : int , datelist : (int*int*int) list) =
          if null (tl datelist)
          then x
          else if #2(hd datelist) = month
            then count (x+1, tl datelist)
            else count (x, tl datelist)
    in
      if #2(hd datelist) = month
      then count (1, datelist)
      else count (0, datelist)
    end


fun number_in_months (datelist : (int*int*int) list, monthlist : int list)=
    let
      fun count (x : int, monthlist : int list)=
          if null (tl monthlist)
          then x
          else count (x + number_in_month(datelist, hd monthlist), tl monthlist)
    in
      count (number_in_month (datelist, hd monthlist), tl monthlist)
    end
```

How to format nested if's is always a great debate where I'm from. Personally I avoid them, and use cases instead but I guess you will lean about that in the future.

However I also spotted a mistake in your count function. When you test whether your second argument (in both of your count functions) are the empty list with `null`, you do it on the tail of the argument, which will fail if the argument is in fact the empty list

```
- null (tl []);

uncaught exception Empty
```

For example this imput

```
- number_in_months ([(1,1,1)], [1]);

uncaught exception Empty
```

Also your logic in `number_in_month` is wrong, as you are testing for the head of the `datelist` being equal to `month`, however your to `count` in either case uses the whole of `datelist` instead of its tail. This is seen as the below should not return 2 as a result

```
- number_in_month([(1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,3)], 1);
val it = 2 : int
```

This error, is the only thing that is making the `number_in_month` function not throwing up an exception.

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you so much

Comment: I have updated the answer with some examples of how to get rid of your count function and some suggested questions/answers that you ought to go and read.

Comment: Found some error in your code, while trying to give an example as to how it ought to be indented. However if you find this to be an answer to your question you might wan't to accept it.

Comment: you are awesome. Thank you for the thorough response

Comment: @AndrewMcLaughlin, you might find that people are more willing to answer your question in the future if you accept the answer, you find the best. [Click the check mark next to the answer, below the up/down vote buttons.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, you are not calculating the last date if it is matching with the month. this code works fine.

```
fun number_in_month (datelist : (int*int*int) list, month : int)  =
    let
      fun count (x : int , datelist : (int*int*int) list) =
          if null (tl datelist)
          then 
              if #2(hd datelist) <> month
                      then x
                     else x+1
         else if #2(hd datelist) = month
            then count (x+1, tl datelist)
            else count (x, tl datelist)
    in
          count (0, datelist)
    end
```